Issue with vertex colors when importing an x3d file in 4.2 (works fine in 2.9)
I work with scientific visualizations and often export scenes as x3d from Paraview (the software I use for post-processing) into Blender (which I then use for rendering). It used to work out quite well. However, I recently moved onto the newer versions of Blender and the workflow can no longer reproduce vertex colors. After a long search on forums, I couldn't find any similar questions. So here we go:
I have this simple square which when exported as an image from within Paraview looks like this:

I export this as an x3d file, import it into Blender 2.9, and render it, boom, I get this:
 (as expected).
When I do the exact same procedure, using the same x3d file, but using 4.2 I get this:

I'm aware that "vertex color" is "color attribute" nowadays. I have tried to come up with a minimum viable example here but my bigger renders also run into the same issue. Their colors show up just fine in 2.9, but 4.2 always has this uniform blue color. The original color information seems "lost" inside 4.2.
Could anyone guide me toward a solution? I can provide more information about the setup if needed.
These are my material settings in 2.9 and 4.2 respectively:
 

Managed to solve it on my own. Funnily enough, after spending several days struggling with this the solution is that I wasn't doing anything wrong. It was the Web3D X3d/VRML2 Add-On version 2.3.5 that was bugged. They patched one single issue in 2.3.6 - the one in this post. (see https://extensions.blender.org/add-ons/web3d-x3d-vrml2-format/versions/)
If someone is in a similar boat, try updating your x3d add-on.
Thanks to those devs. I can now finally upgrade to the new blender.
